# Simplicial model for $\Sigma^{\infty}_+ \Omega^{\infty}X$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Let $Sp^{\Sigma}$ be the category of symmetric spectra, and let $Sp^{\Sigma}-alg$ be the associated category of augmented commutative algebras. These are simplicial categories.

A question for experts:  Can anyone give me a reference for, or explain a construction of, a *simplicial* functor
$$ Sp^{\Sigma} \rightarrow Sp^{\Sigma}-alg$$
which looks like the functor $X \mapsto \Sigma^{\infty}_+ \Omega^{\infty}X$ in the homotopy category?

Nick Kuhn

Comment: Nick, why are you adding "+"? Isn't the relevant functor given by $X \mapsto  \Sigma^\infty \Omega^\infty X$?

Comment: John: To have the suspension spectrum of an $E_{\infty}$ space, or more simply, a topological monoid,  be a ring spectrum  one needs to add a basepoint.  (Think about it.)   The output is then, in fact, a ring spectrum augmented over the sphere spectrum.   By the way, I have answers to my question obtained in more traditional ways.

Comment: Oh yeah, I should have realized that....Well, so much for MO on the flu.